# Intermittent kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL 9813 error

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection for calls to an API server over HTTPS.  Today I got this error for the first 2 or 3 calls after launching the app, and after that it went back to working:

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

What can cause this to happen intermittently?  Normally it works fine, both in iOS and a browser, so I can't think of an obvious configuration problem on the server.  But if it's not reliable for the end user and can fail randomly, it's obviously a concern.

SSL cert is from NameCheap, if that makes a difference.  App is running on iOS 7.  Saw the error both on simulator and device, but can't reliably reproduce.

Comment: I have the same error. All other HTTP calls are fine. Just one is blowing, but it is consistent. Were you able to resolve this? Thanks